# How to design this table schema (and how to query it)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table that stores a list of members - for the sake of simplicity, I will use a simple real-world case that models my use case.

Let's use the analogy of a sports club or gym.

The membership of the gym changes every three months (for example) - with some old members leaving, some new members joining and some members staying unchanged.

I want to run a query on the table - spanning a multi-time period and return the average weight of all of the members in the club.

These are the tables I have come up with so far:

```
-- A table containing all members the gym has ever had
-- current members have their leave_date field left at NULL
-- departed members have their leave_date field set to the days they left the gym
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS member (
                   id              PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                   name            TEXT NOT NULL,
                   join_date       DATE NOT NULL,

                   -- set to NULL if user has not left yet
                   leave_date      DATE DEFAULT NULL
        );


-- A table of members weights. 
-- This table is populated DAILY,after the weights of CURRENT members
-- has been recorded
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS current_member_weight (
                   id              PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                   calendar_date   DATE NOT NULL,
                   member_id       INTEGER REFERENCES member(id) NOT NULL,
                   weight          REAL NOT NULL
       );


-- I want to write a query that returns the AVERAGE daily weight of
-- CURRENT members of the gym. The query should take a starting_date
-- and an ending_date between which to calculate the daily 
-- averages. The aver

-- PSEUDO SQL BELOW!
SELECT calendar_date, AVG(weight) 
FROM member, current_member_weight
WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN(starting_date, ending_date);
```

I have two questions:

1. can the schema above be improved - if yes, please illustrate
2. How can I write an SQL* query to return the average weights calculated for all members in the gym during a specified period (t1, t2), where (t1,t2) spans a period that members have joined/left the gym?

**[[Note about SQL]]**

Preferably, any SQL shown would be database anagnostic, however if a particular flavour of SQL is to be used, I'd prefer PostgreSQL, since that this is the database I'm using.

Comment: I would change the table names and drop the 3rd table because you can just query that and as soon as you store it it will become outdated.

Comment: @juergend Dropped third table as you suggested, to clarify the question. Regarding changing the table names - what names do your suggest?

Comment: Actually I do not know that the difference between a member and a gym_member. Maybe use USERS and MEMBERSHIP. There is a better word for membership but I cant recall it right now

Comment: You are not clear re what's in your tables or what query result you want. Please finish these sentences: Row (*id*, *name*, ...) is in Member when person *id* has name *name* ... and left on *leave_date* or hasn't left and *leave_date* is null; Row (*id*, ...) is in Gym_Member when ...; Row (*calendar_date*, *weight*) is in the query result when for some person *id*  ...". PS What if one left & rejoined? PPS "Essentially" when not summarizing clearness elsewhere is a waffle word meaning "not" that lets one pretend to oneself that one has been clear enough when one knows or suspects one hasn't.

Comment: @philipxy Ironically, I don't understand what you mean either. Could you please transcribe this statement: *"Essentially" when not summarizing clearness elsewhere is a waffle word meaning "not" that lets one pretend to oneself that one has been clear enough when one knows or suspects one hasn't."* into English please?

Comment: "Essentially" reasonably precedes a vague description summarizing/introducing/distilling/paraphrasing a clear description elsewhere, a vague/informal *essence*. But it doesn't add or clarify if the vague description is all there is. Like "virtually spotless" for "almost, but *not*, spotless", "essentially X" is "sort of, but *not*, X". But one tells oneself that one is capturing some kind of gist while simultaneously contradictorily that one is owning up to not even being (as known/suspected) clear--one waffles/equivocates--while conveniently obfuscating that they have. Just work to be clear.

Comment: @philipxy Methinks one needs to get off one's **bloody high horse**; this is neither [EnglishStackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) nor the place to be a pedantic bore. You're not adding anything remotely useful to the conversation, even though you may feel that you are (Dunning Kruger springs to mind). No one is forcing you to answer this question, if you don't want to answer it (or more likely can't), then simply toodle along - there's a good chap!

Comment: You're not clear, and if you want to get a good answer, be clear. I told you the best way I know how to be clear here--namely, finish those sentences. And I have tried to explain a relevant way people manage to not bother to be clear, in case that helps, since your question exhibits it. If you thought you were definitely clear, you wouldn't have prefaced your spec with "essentially". It's unfortunate that you think I have some kind of attitude instead of experience in reading a lot of unclear writing.

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL would work as long as the data in the gym_member table is consistent with the joining and leaving date of each member (i.e. for any member, the gym_member table should not have rows with calendar_date less his joining date or with calendar_date greater than his leaving date)

```
SELECT
    gm.calendar_date,
    AVG(gm.weight) avg_weight
FROM
    member m,
    gym_member gm
WHERE
        m.id = gm.member_id
    AND
        gm.calendar_date >= '1-Jan-2017'
    AND
        gm.calendar_date <= '31-Dec-2017'
GROUP BY
    gm.calendar_date
```

Comment: Difficult to understand this staement with two negatives: `does NOT have rows for days when a person was NOT a member`. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I think this may be **a** correct solution. I'l test it later, and accept it if it works for my use case.